Java process memory usage with native memory details

JDK Version: 21.
Min Heap: 1GB
Max Heap: 1.5GB
Application deployed over VM.

Below is the native memory captured.
         Native Memory Tracking:

         (Omitting categories weighting less than 1KB)

          Total: reserved=2661938KB +172KB, committed=1667126KB +4136KB

            Java Heap (reserved=1572864KB, committed=1048576KB)
                        (mmap: reserved=1572864KB, committed=1048576KB)

                Class (reserved=220773KB -35KB, committed=33125KB -35KB)
                        (classes #37376 -47)
                        (  instance classes #34947 -48, array classes #2429 +1)
                        (malloc=7781KB -35KB #190298 -605)
                        (mmap: reserved=212992KB, committed=25344KB)
                       : (  Metadata)
                        (    reserved=196608KB, committed=189760KB +256KB)
                        (    used=188269KB +272KB)
                        (    waste=1491KB =0.79% -16KB)
                       : (  Class space)
                        (    reserved=212992KB, committed=25344KB)
                        (    used=23586KB -24KB)
                        (    waste=1758KB =6.93% +24KB)

                Thread (reserved=173615KB, committed=21295KB -32KB)
                        (thread #169)
                        (stack: reserved=173056KB, committed=20736KB -32KB)
                        (malloc=362KB #1028)
                        (arena=197KB #337)

                 Code (reserved=255864KB -33KB, committed=145824KB +3707KB)
                        (malloc=8176KB -33KB #18349 -1301)
                        (mmap: reserved=247688KB, committed=137648KB +3740KB)

                   GC (reserved=77299KB -54KB, committed=67059KB -54KB)
                        (malloc=13603KB -54KB #41258 -1034)
                        (mmap: reserved=63696KB, committed=53456KB)

            GCCardSet (reserved=401KB -5KB, committed=401KB -5KB)
                        (malloc=401KB -5KB #3230 -60)


             Compiler (reserved=1977KB -42KB, committed=1977KB -42KB)
                        (malloc=1814KB -42KB #2053 -102)
                        (arena=164KB #4)

             Internal (reserved=25719KB +95KB, committed=25715KB +95KB)
                        (malloc=25679KB +95KB #136779 +1293)
                        (mmap: reserved=40KB, committed=36KB)

                Other (reserved=4898KB +273KB, committed=4898KB +273KB)
                        (malloc=4898KB +273KB #1013 +22)

               Symbol (reserved=57938KB +3KB, committed=57938KB +3KB)
                        (malloc=52816KB +3KB #525441 +218)
                        (arena=5122KB #1)

   Native Memory Tracking (reserved=16727KB +281KB, committed=16727KB +281KB)
                        (malloc=1130KB +247KB #13714 +3278)
                        (tracking overhead=15597KB +34KB)

   Shared class space (reserved=16384KB, committed=12960KB)
                        (mmap: reserved=16384KB, committed=12960KB)

          Arena Chunk (reserved=8KB -32KB, committed=8KB -32KB)
                        (malloc=8KB -32KB)

              Tracing (reserved=34693KB -250KB, committed=34693KB -250KB)
                        (malloc=34629KB -250KB #15332 +608)
                        (arena=64KB #2)

               Module (reserved=513KB -8KB, committed=513KB -8KB)
                        (malloc=513KB -8KB #7411 -18)

            Safepoint (reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)
                        (mmap: reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)

      Synchronization (reserved=4053KB -11KB, committed=4053KB -11KB)
                        (malloc=4053KB -11KB #39881 -106)

       Serviceability (reserved=20KB, committed=20KB)
                        (malloc=20KB #50)

            Metaspace (reserved=198160KB -9KB, committed=191312KB +247KB)
                        (malloc=1552KB -9KB #1706 -29)
                        (mmap: reserved=196608KB, committed=189760KB +256KB)

 String Deduplication (reserved=1KB, committed=1KB)
                        (malloc=1KB #8)

      Object Monitors (reserved=24KB, committed=24KB)
                        (malloc=24KB #120 -1)

Below is the process RSS memory graph.

The graph shows around 1.97GB memory but the native memory details shows around 1.67GB of committed memory. So there is different of around 300MB. If I increased the min heap and max heap this difference also grow.
Is this is expected or there is any other memory details which is not part of native memory and how to see the details of that memory ?
